# How can I store multiple rowsets in 1 variable sql

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, join

I have a join where i have a many to many relationship between categories and courses....I use multiple join in CodeIgniter with Active Record. My code looks like this:

```
$query = $this->db->select('*')
             ->from('subscriptions')
             ->where('subscriptions.user_id', $user_id)
             ->join('courses', 'courses.id=subscriptions.course_id')
             ->join('course_categories', 'course_categories.course_id=courses.id')
             ->join('categories', 'categories.id=course_categories.category_id')
             ->join('tutor_profiles', 'tutor_profiles.id=courses.tutor_id')
             ->get();
```

I have a problem retrieving multiple categories for 1 course...i want to have something like categories = array(JOIN RESULT). I mean i want to retrieve the results from the join of the categories in 1 sql variable that is an array and loop the results after.
How can I do this? Or do I need to make 2 queries?

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly? I mean, what do you want the results of the query to be?

Comment: to get a course with it's tutor and all it's categories based on a user subscription. Sorry for not beeing clear on that matter

Comment: And your query should be returning multiples rows (one per category per course), so the data you need should be there. Isn't it?

Comment: i want to get 1 course with all it's categories

Comment: What you want is not possible in MySQL (there is no array datatype). Why don't you just loop the query results from the controller and create a PHP array of categories from there?

Answer (score 2):

You should try to serialize your result and save it in db

Comment: +1 Serialize to either XML or preferably JSON. A short example here would be nice.

Comment: After getting your db result. If we consider that $result is an array containing all join value. You can do $result = serialize($result); . The var result will be a string. To recover the initial state use unserialize($result); ;)